# Cannot Play VCD

Tags: video, vcd

I am using ubuntu 10.10 64bit. The problem is that no VCD's can be played. I tried Totem, mplayer,vlc etc etc. None of the players can render the file and show either show I/O error or parse error. I even tried copying the .dat files but it shows me a permission denied error ( even in root mode file browser). Vcd's work in Windows as well as VCD player. So neither the discs nor the drive is faulty. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to play the .dat file using VLC or did you do this: VLC Media Player > Media > Open Disk > SVCD/VCD > Play?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the data is corrupted. This may be deliberate; used for DRM. See if the method outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13071/how-can-i-read-every-dvd-even-if-encrypted-by-css-or-other/13095#13095) works.

Answer (score 0):

click on open cd/dvd from file menu in vlc if that cd is an vcd that can be played on cd player or perhaps change the player or get codecs for vlc

Answer (score 0):

Install mplayer without gui and try running your video from terminal.I am using it for a longtime and none of the videos failed for me.

```
sudo aptitude -y install mplayer-nogui
```

To play video's from terminal type the following,

```
mplayer /path/to/your/video/file
```

If you dont want to have mplayer,then i would recommend you to install the following codec pack

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Also i recommend you to go through this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) for detailed instruction and troubleshooting.